# Undefined is not a function when calling getZIndez() for Google Maps polygon

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have a Google Map in my view and i'm adding lots of polygons to it. The problem is that i have polygons of different sizes, overlapping. i need to set the z-index for each polygon so i can use the click listener properly.

The process should be straight forward, but as i noticed, it isn't.
I'm hit with this error when trying to call either the getZIndex() method or setZindex().

```
Undefined is not a function (evaluating 'shape.setZIndex()')
```

This is my code:

```
function attachMap(params){
    removeMap();
    var options = $.extend(true, {
        shapesData: [],
        shapeClick: function(event){}
    },params);

    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 5,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(24.886436490787712, -70.2685546875),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
    };

    // Create the Google Maps shapes and append them to the map
    shapes = [];
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('dxf-shapes'), mapOptions);
    if(typeof options.shapesData != "undefined") {
        $.each(options.shapesData, function (shapeIndex, shapeData) {
            var paths = [];
            // points of the shape
            $.each(shapeData.points, function (pointIndex, pointData) {
                var mapsPoint = new google.maps.LatLng(pointData.lat, pointData.lng);
                paths.push(mapsPoint);
            });

            // new shape from the points
            var shape = new google.maps.Polygon({
                paths: paths,
                strokeColor: 'rgb(' + shapeData.color + ')',
                strokeOpacity: 1,
                strokeWeight: 1.5,
                fillColor: 'rgb(' + shapeData.color + ')',
                fillOpacity: 0,
                geodesic: true,
                zIndex: 1
            });

            shapes.push(shape);
        });

        shapes.sort(function(a, b){
            var aArea = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeArea(a.getPath());
            var bArea = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeArea(b.getPath());

            if( aArea < bArea ){
                return -1;
            }
            if(aArea > bArea){
                return 1;
            }

            return 0;
        });

        var zIndex = 0;
        $.each(shapes, function(index, shape){
            zIndex++;
            //append the shape to the map
            shape.setMap(map);
            shape.setZIndex(zIndex);

            google.maps.event.addListener(shape, 'click', options.shapeClick);
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't recommend extending Maps API object prototypes and relying on undocumented behavior (the `get` and `set` of `zIndex`) as shown in your answer.

It is better if you can use only the documented API. In your code, you are not using `getZIndex` at all, so get rid of it. And where you call `shape.setZIndex(zIndex);`, simply change it to:

```
shape.setOptions({ zIndex: zIndex });
```

Now you are using only documented Maps API properties and methods. This makes your code more future-proof.

Comment: Thank you very much; fixed it already. I was really trying to avoid this kind of hacks, but i couldn't get passed it. The solution you proposed, didn't even pass through my head. It works.

Answer (score 0):

The problem has been fized by adding the methods setZIndex() and getZIndex() to the polygon type.

```
google.maps.Polygon.prototype.getZIndex=function(){return (this.get('zIndex')||0);};
google.maps.Polygon.prototype.setZIndex=function(v){this.set('zIndex',v);};
```

Hope this will help someone in the future.